# Next.js server router's asPath property is equal to a static file path

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js

I have the next.js app with ISR and I'm using `getStaticProps`. My pages' structure is like this: `/pages/page1/[[...subpages]].tsx`.

`getStaticPaths` for the page1 return the array like

```
{ 
  params: { subpages: ['subpage1'] },
  params: { subpages: ['subpage2'] },
  params: { subpages: [] }
}
```

In my next.js app, I'm logging the result of `useRouter` function in one of my components. When I open /page1/subpage1 from address bar, sometimes the valid object is logged on the server with `asPath: '/page1/subpage1'` and the right query, but sometimes (when I do the same) I get the following object logged on the server:

```
serve_1  | router1 ServerRouter {
serve_1  |   route: '/page1/[[...subpages]]',
serve_1  |   pathname: '/page1/[[...subpages]]',
serve_1  |   query: { },
serve_1  |   asPath: '/page1/_next/data/kk/page1/subpage1.json',
serve_1  |   basePath: '',
serve_1  |   events: undefined,
serve_1  |   isFallback: false
serve_1  | }
```

I would like to ask if anybody has any idea why the logs are inconsistent and sometimes showing the path to json file as `asPath`? Also for some requests (to the same exact url) `getStaticProps` is run once, and for other twice.